# how to update specific row in mysql database without using INDEX

Tags: php, mysql

How can i refer to a specific row in a table without using column or primary key?
I simply want to update lets say a 3rd row in a table but I dont want to use a column with a index on that column.

Comment: That depends on what you mean by the `third` row.  Chances are you won't run into any issues, but you shouldn't assume that the rows are internally ordered in any particular way.

Comment: By 3rd row I mean 3rd row as such, in a table. That means row 3rd row from the top no matter what number is in index (if there is one that is)

Answer (score 0):

Add `LIMIT 2,1` to limit row number 3. Change the `2` to affect whatever row you want, but it's probably better to also add `ORDER BY` on a key.

Comment: ok i see. But can you use LIMIT with UPDATE or just SELECT? Btw the way I just found that you can probably use WHERE ROWNUM = theRowNumber, gonna try it

Comment: I don't know if the offset of `LIMIT` works with `UPDATE`, but I do know that just `LIMIT 1` will update at most one row.